# Allow URL Parameters in Joomla

Tags: url, joomla, parameters

i am setting up a Joomla (2.5) Website using internal SEO URLs. The URLs look like the following http://www.mydomain.com/category/article.htm

Inside the article i am using some custom php code to fetch data from a different database and display it. While i want to link to an "offer" now, i want to use the seo-friendly url, but also use the url to provide some parameters to the target URL site, for example :

http://www.mydomain.com/category/article.htm?id=100

When doing this i always get my defined error page or fallback to the main site. Is there a way to allow parameters in the url but still calling the proper page?

Thanks for any advice

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution while asking.

I used the SEO-URL in the href="" attribute such  as

```
<a href="category/article.htm?id?<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"</a>
```

while i needed to use the absolute url such as

```
index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=47&Itemid=155 and
```

Joomla recognized the URL, transformed it into the SEO-URL and added the parameters without the fallback.

:)